# Working with Large Number of csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, parallel-processing

I have a directory containing ~40000 csv files, each ranging in size from ~400 bytes to ~11 MB. I have written a function that reads in a csv file and calculates some basic numbers for each csv file (eq. how many values of "female" are in each csv file). This code successfully ran for the same number of csv files, but when the csv files were smaller.

I'm using the packages `parallel` and `doParallel` to run this on my machine and receive the following error:

```
Error in unserialize(node$con) : error reading from connection
```

I suspect I'm running out of memory but I am not sure how best to handle the increased size of the files I'm working with. My code is as follows:

Say that 'fpath' is the path to my directory where all these csvs live:

```
fpath<-"../Desktop/bigdirectory"   


filelist <- as.vector(list.files(fpath,pattern="site.csv"))
(f <- file.path(fpath,filelist))

# demographics csv in specified directory
dlist <- as.vector(list.files(fpath,pattern="demographics.csv"))
(d <- file.path(fpath,dlist))
demos <- fread(d,header=T,sep=",")


cl <- makeCluster(4)

registerDoParallel(cl)
setDefaultCluster(cl)
clusterExport(NULL,c('transit.grab'))
clusterEvalQ(NULL,library(data.table))

sdemos <- demo.grab(dl[[1]],demos)
stmp   <- parLapply(cl,f,FUN=transit.grab,sdemos)
```

And the function 'transit.grab' is the following:

```
    transit.grab <- function(sitefile,selected.demos){

    require(sqldf)

    demos <- selected.demos

    # Renaming sitefile columns
    sf           <- fread(sitefile,header=T,sep=",")
    names(sf)[1] <- c("id")

    # Selecting transits from site file using list of selected users
    sdat <- sqldf('select sf.* from sf inner join demos on sf.id=demos.id')
return(sdat)
}
```

I'm not looking for someone to debug code, as I know it runs properly for a smaller amount of data, but rather I desperately need suggestions on how to implement this code for ~6.7 GB of data. Any and all feedback is welcome, thanks!

UPDATE:
As suggested, I replaced `sqldf()` with `merge()`, which reduced my computation time by half when tested on a smaller directory. When observing my memory usage via Activity Monitor, my trend is pretty flat. BUT now when I try running my code on the large directory, my R session crashes.

Comment: You can verify if this is a memory probable by trying it with your system monitor / task manager/ whatever it's called on your OS on and checking the memory trend.

Comment: I presume that the total size of all your `sdat` objects is what hits 6.7 Gb. If so, you may need to create and save them in chunks (of, say, 10k files).

Comment: If you use `sqldf(...whatever..., dbname = tempfile())` it will use an external file rather than memory for the database.

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck Great suggestion to avoid using sqldf, I replaced it with 'merge' and cut my memory usage and CPU time in half for a smaller directory. Unfortunately, now R crashes completely.

Comment: @timriffe My apologies for the confusion, the total size of the directory I am working with (bigdirectory) is 6.7 GB. From my Activity Monitor, my memory trend is pretty flat now that I've replaced 'sqldf' with 'merge'