# Automate reading of CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm working with NOAA's database of storm events - 1951 to 2015. Code and CSVs in link.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lb69l5isa25guc2/AAC4-gYr3N6TVDxEGzBB8fJVa?dl=0

The code is done, but I had to repeat the following two lines 65 times, changing only a couple things manually:

```
x52 <- read.csv("StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d1952_c20160223.csv")
n52 <- length(select(x52, EVENT_TYPE) %>% filter(EVENT_TYPE=="Tornado") %>% unlist)
```

Is there a way to tell R to assign each new CSV you read to a new vector (for 1953, 54 etc), and to perform the same operations on all of them? I found this thread but I don't it's exactly the same question: [Working with Large Number of csv files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222282/working-with-large-number-of-csv-files-in-r)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, if the various data frames have the same columns, you could `rbind()` them all together, and then perform your operation on them.  Is this the case?  If the data being read in is very different, then it's probably going to have to be different strokes for different folks ^ ^

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have all the files and put them in one directory. You could do something similar to this:

```
datFiles <- c(list.files(path = "c:/Users/Philip/Downloads/Tornadoes/",
    pattern = "StormEvents_details.*\\.csv$",
    all.files = FALSE, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE,
    include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE))

for (i in 1:length(datFiles)) {
    x[i] <- read.csv(datFiles[i])
    n[i] <- length(select(x[i], EVENT_TYPE) %>% filter(EVENT_TYPE=="Tornado") %>% unlist)
    <your code here>
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. With that code I get the error message: `no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "list"` Will google a bit more - I tried replacing list.files with bind_cols or rbind but so far no luck.